# Proper way to configure Google Eclipse Plugin with Maven

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven-2, google-eclipse-plugin

I know this question has appeared few times, but the things are changing really fast and I got a little bit confused. I was developing my GWT (2.2.0) application using Maven (m2Eclipse) in Eclipse (J2SE 3.6) with Google Eclipse Plugin (the newest version, as of April 2011) and it mostly worked fine, until bang! nothing works:) I keep my project in SVN without any Eclipse-specific configuration files, and I failed in recovering the environment.

So, I tried looking for some solution in the web, and I found the tutorial from the gwt-maven-plugin site, and the new tutorial from the Google Eclipse Plugin site, but none of them worked - I was still getting the 404 error, and a lot of classpath errors.

Could someone please show me the proper way to run the GWT project in Eclipse with Google Eclipse Plugin using Maven?

Here's the pom.xml file for the project: http://pastebin.com/evujwD5F

And the project's structure looks like this:

```
|-src
  |-main
    |-java
      |-org.halish.books (package)
        |-client
          |-(some client stuff)
        |-server
          |-(server side, async implementations and stuff)
        |-share
          |-(shared)
        |-BooksApp.gwt.xml
    |-resources
      |-(nothing here)
    |-webapp
      |-META-INF
        |-persistence.xml
        |-log4j.properties
      |-WEB-INF
        |-web.xml
      |-BooksApp.html
      |-BooksApp.css
|-pom.xml
```

I'd be really grateful for your help.

Regards,
mh

Comment: This stuff is stupid-hard.  Also, anyone who thinks that XML is an acceptable UI needs to have their developers license revoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pretty much the same project structure! My best suggestion (as I struggled to get maven working) is to get you a sample project already working. I did it to kick off my project and a couple of times I couldn't repair my POM (I broke it :(

My **module.gwt.xml** is at the same place as you. It's hard to tell just by reading your POM but it might be easier to just "copy" your stuff with a new POM.

[Simple project with GWT](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/source/browse/#hg/gwtp-samples)

[A bit more complex and using objectify](http://code.google.com/p/listwidget/)